# Генератор из xml в MS Word

Tags: java, xml, apache-poi

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]пытаюсь сделать генератор из *xml* в *ms word*. использую для этой цели *apache poi*.

«застрял» в этом моменте:

```
for (SheetType sa:sheetArray) { 

    changeOrientation(document, sa.getLandscape());
    TableType[] colArray = sa.getTableArray();
    RowType[] rowArray = sa.getRowArray();
    XWPFTable table = document.createTable();
  for (RowType ra : rowArray) {

        XWPFTableRow tableRowOne = table.createRow();
        CellsType[] cellArray = ra.getCellArray();


        //Массив cells
        for (CellsType ca : cellArray) {

            CellsType.Value[] valueArray = ca.getValueArray();

            //Массив values
            for (CellsType.Value value : valueArray) {
                XWPFTableCell cell = tableRowOne.addNewTableCell();


                XWPFParagraph paragraph = cell.addParagraph();
                XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();

                tableRowOne.setHeight((int) ra.getHeigth());
                table.setCellMargins(
                        sa.getPositionTop(),
                        sa.getPositionLeft(),
                        sa.getPositionBottom(),
                        sa.getPositionRight()
                );
                run.setText(value.getStringValue());
                run.setBold(ca.getBold());
                run.setItalic(ca.getItalic());
                run.setUnderline(UnderlinePatterns.valueOf(ca.getUnderline()));
                run.setFontFamily(ca.getFontName());
                run.setFontSize(ca.getFontSize());
                paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.valueOf(ca.getTextAlign()));
                paragraph.setBorderBottom(Borders.valueOf(ca.getBorderBottom()));
                paragraph.setBorderLeft(Borders.valueOf(ca.getBorderLeft()));
                paragraph.setBorderTop(Borders.valueOf(ca.getBorderTop()));
                paragraph.setBorderRight(Borders.valueOf(ca.getBorderRight()));
                paragraph.setSpacingAfter((short)ca.getSpacingAfter());
                table.setInsideHBorder(
                        XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.valueOf(colArray[0].getTableBorderType()),
                        Integer.parseInt(colArray[0].getTableBorderSize()),
                        colArray[0].getTableBorderPosition(),
                        colArray[0].getTableBorderColor()
                );
                cell.removeParagraph(0);
                run.setColor(ca.getColor());
                run.setSubscript(VerticalAlign.valueOf(ca.getSubscript()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

все данные я беру из *xml*, но после моего итератора появляется лишняя *Cell*.

`removeCell` — не помогает.

**На выходе я должен был получит таблицу но у меня создается лишняя ячейка и столбец.**
в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как то так

```
 XWPFTable table = document.createTable(rowArray.length, sa.getColArray().length);
```